# Twig posting empty modules on page

Tags: php, symfony, twig, include

I'm working with Twig in Craft and am trying to include a module I've made, I have added all the content into the modules in the CMS and saved it, they show on the page correctly, but a tonne of empty paragraph tags show also, does anyone know why this is?

Steps I took:

I have a twig file called "Abilities.twig", inside abilities I have the below code:

```
<p>{{ module.Abilities }}</p>
```

In Index.twig I have the below:

```
{% for module in entry.modals %}
    {% include '_modals/Abilities' %}
{% endfor %}
```

An example below of how they show on the page

```
<p>This is the first example of an ability</p>
<p>This is the second example of an ability</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

In the CMS the only modules that are shown are the top 2 examples, there are no empty modules saved.

If anyone can help would appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to have the "extra" `<p>`'s you need to verify the content is not empty

```
{% if module.Abilities | trim != '' %}
    <p>{{ module.Abilities }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I just tried this with a block and it's not working - works great for fields inside blocks, but I have an examples.twig then I have 2 fields inside that so you can add more in the CMS without having to code anything, I'm assuming it's not working because I put module.examples, I'm assuming I have to reference the block and not the 2 fields inside it so i put block.examples, but that also threw an error, do you know the proper way to reference the block for the statement above? if I do it without the above statement I again end up with empty components... is there something up with the CMS?

Comment: You'd need to add an if around any field you add. If you don't want to add the extra `if's` around each field I'd suggest to place the `<p>` inside your content

Comment: Thanks that worked, wasn't working coz I wrapped both fields in one if statement, is there a reason why this needs to be done? how come the CMS includes more modules than there are content for? I'd imagine it should automatically stop empty modules from displaying right?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an if statement in you loop

```
{% for module in entry.modals if module != null %}
    {% include '_modals/Abilities' %}
{% endfor %}
```